# Should AI Generated Answers Be Allowed

Tags: discussion, status-review

Should we have a stance on AI generated answers (and possible questions as well)?

- AI generated answers are not allowed as they can be tricky to verify as correct and it can be said if you are using AI to generate an answer you won't be able to verify if it is correct or not.
- <s>AI generated answers are allowed but need to be properly cited as an AI generated answer to allow users to know the source of the answer.</s>(All AI generated content is required to be cited per SE policy)
- <s>AI Generated answers are treated like all others and no special actions are needed for them</s>(not allowed per stack exchange)

As a note I am asking this question as there are new banners available for answers to indicate that they are not allowed or not

[Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera?cb=1)

Comment: @murgatroid99 can this question be featured to try and increase the visibility

Comment: That is a good point. I have featured this question.

Comment: Regarding #3: AI answers that are _not_ clearly listed as AI are [considered a Code of Conduct violation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682) under the Inauthentic Usage policy, and so are essentially prohibited already. Making a _more_ restrictive policy is, of course, totally fine.

Comment: @cocomac If that was the case why is there an option to have a banner warning users that all AI generated answers have to be properly identified? "**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more" That option suggests that it isn't required to state that AI is used in an answer.

Comment: @JoeW I'm not sure exactly what you mean. An AI answer listed as an AI answer is allowed by the Inauthentic Usage policy, so having a banner reminding users to state that they used AI is fine. A banner saying that a site decided to fully ban AI and to not use it is fine as well.

Comment: @cocomac My point is that if it was true that an AI generated/edited answer has to have a statement listing it as AI why would one of the choices listed in the post I link be to add a banner stating that AI answers must be noted as such. The fact that it is a choice to turn on for a site suggests that posting AI answers without listing them as such is allowable. That question is saying sites can have a banner saying AI answers are not allowed, AI answers must be identified or no banner at all. You should post an answer explaining why you think they are not allowed without reference.

Comment: The community consensus is clearly against AIG material being permitted at all. Why has this post been edited to say they are okay with referencing? This is neither necessary nor desirable. @murgatroid99

Comment: @Nij I think there is a misunderstanding with the edit, the update was to remove the option of saying that AI content must be cited because that is already a sitewide requirement. When they asked the question of which type of banner a site wanted they missed the fact that all AI answers where already required to be cited under the inauthentic use policy.

Comment: @JoeW the edit is somewhat poor, probably best would have been to just remove option 3 from the points list, the option for allowing without referencing the AI generation, as it stands this asks a question and appears to give a single option (granted the one it seems our community agrees on) and still lists the third, no longer Stack Exchange permitted option in the edit notes beside the second option that would be stack exchange permitted.

Comment: @Andrew The attempt of the edit was to explain why it was being removed, if you feel you can do a better job feel free to make an edit yourself.

Comment: @JoeW done, how's that look?

Comment: @Andrew Option 2 is also no longer available as all AI answers are required to be properly citied based on existing SE policies. The  meta question that sparked this question has also been updated to reflect that.

Comment: @JoeW Option 2 IS still available, because it is the alternative to Option 1, Option 1 is we do not allow AI content, option 2 is we do allow AI content (with the required citations). Option 3 is the only one no longer available as it violates the SE policy that citations are required on AI content, option 2 is the answer that allows and requires citations and meets SE policy.

Comment: @Andrew I removed it as an option from my question as it was only included due to the incorrect information that citing AI answers was not already required on all sites.  This question was asked about adding new requirements around them and not just restating an existing rule. Please don't roll back my edit again.

Comment: @Andrew "As was pointed out in the comment thread by Joe W (thank you!), our current Code of Conduct (more specifically, its Inauthentic Usage policy) prohibits posting AI-generated content without appropriate attribution (explanation here). With that in mind, it doesn’t make sense that the “answers must be cited” variant, shown below as one of the possible two options for sites to opt-in to, would be optional. As such, we’ll be rolling out the “answers must be cited” option as the default for all Stack Exchange sites in the coming weeks."

Comment: @JoeW This is a question asking what this site should do, it DOES make sense that the answers must be cited variant is one of the options, because as a question it needs 2 choices minimum to make sense, Option 1 is no we should not allow them at all, option 2 is yes we should allow them (in line with the SE policies on citations), option 3 is the only one that should be removed because if violates the SE policies - the options are do we keep the default minimum or do we ban outright, we still have the choice and we still need to consider both.

Comment: If you want to remove it you need a major structural rewrite to the question to be in line with a "should we do something or nothing", remove the bullet points, ask it open ended, and point out the minimums in that case, without providing any options at all, instead of the more "here are our choices, which should we choose" as it was originally written.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151449/discussion-between-andrew-and-joe-w).

Comment: @Andrew There is nothing to continue in chat, the second option is being added to every site by default and there is no longer a choice to request to add it or not.

Comment: There's a fundamental disagreement on what we're discussing, and why the option still belongs, so there is more to continue in chat - in the words of Neil Peart "If you chose not to decide, you still have made a choice" it's still an option, either the default minimum or to choose to reject all AI content - you have presented a choice here "reject AI content or...." with nothing after the or in the ways you have edited your question

Comment: @Andrew In the end it is my question and my decision on what should be in it. Also I have pointed out how the question I reference has been updated to state that the second option is no longer something to choose from and will be added to all sites by default.

Comment: Why is the option, "AI generated answers are allowed but need to be properly cited" struck through even though that is a valid option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We should not allow the use of AI for answers on this site.

AI has proven to be unreliable, making answers that sound reasonable but are out and out false or wrong. It can be used for creative writing, and as a tool for other things but usually needs work after the fact. There's an extra risk on a site like ours where an answer given could have been correct, but no longer is, [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) is the most common tag on BGSE, Magic is a game with changing rules, and a large language model AI is very capable of giving once true, but no longer correct, answers.

In general though AI answers run counter to the entire point of Stack Exchange, getting an answer from experts, or at least people with more experience in a topic. If people wanted an answer from an AI, they could just ask the AI their question directly.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that we do not allow AI answers on this site as they can be very difficult to verify if they are correct or not and based on writing style can easily be taken as a correct answer when they are not. I feel this way as when an AI is used to generate an answer the required knowledge will not be present to verify if it is accurate or not.

Answer (score 5):

While I have an opinion about AI, I'm not going to say right now what I think this site should do - I'm not a regular of this site, and I don't really know it. This "answer" is regarding option #3, which states "AI Generated answers are treated like all others and no special actions are needed for them
".

Tl;dr: **AI answers that are *not* clearly listed as AI answers violate the Inauthentic Usage policy, which is part of the Stack Exchange Code of Conduct.** This [has been confirmed by a SE Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682) (staff). Per [the Moderator Agreement](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement), diamond (i.e., elected or appointed) mods are expected to enforce the CoC. How mods handle AI-content (as a CoC violation) is, to an extent, up to them. But, individual sites aren't really supposed to make policies overriding the CoC. You cannot, for example, make a policy that allows being intentionally rude to other users.

---

To respond to your comment:

> @cocomac My point is that if it was true that an AI generated/edited answer has to have a statement listing it as AI why would one of the choices listed in the post I link be to add a banner stating that AI answers must be noted as such. The fact that it is a choice to turn on for a site suggests that posting AI answers without listing them as such is allowable. That question is saying sites can have a banner saying AI answers are not allowed, AI answers must be identified or no banner at all. You should post an answer explaining why you think they are not allowed without reference.

AI content that is improperly referenced (i.e., not cited as such) [is clearly banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682), regardless of whether or not there is a banner announcing it. A lack of a banner does not mean something is permitted. It's entirely possible for a site to say "We don't want the banner", and, for example, deciding they will ban all AI content, whether cited or not.

Comment: Thank you for this information and explanation of why it is considered a violation.

Comment: As an update the post has been updated that they will be making an update to help center articles community wide to note that AI articles need to be properly cited.